# Redirecting to PHP file in Flask

Tags: php, python, flask

I am running a localhost website using Flask and python. I have some php files that I want to run when the users click a button. Problem is that Flask isn't recognizing the PHP file as PHP code and the code is showing up as text on the webpage. It's showing the text of all the echo statements, but the words in those statements correspond to variable in the code that allow the user to login and logout of the website. What do I do?

Python Code:

```
@app.route('/example.php')
def phpexample():
    return render_template('example.php')
```

This shows a html page with text resulting from the `echo` statements.

The PHP code (example.php):

```
<?php
    require ('steamauth/steamauth.php');  
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Eliminate Phishers! Join Steap now</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-wide.css" />
        </noscript>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

        <!-- Header -->
            <div id="header">
                <span class="logo icon fa-paper-plane-o"></span>
                <h1>Welcome. This is Steap</h1>
                <p>A website designed to help eliminate phishers 
                <br />
                and hackers on Steam.</p>
            </div>

        <!-- Main -->
            <div id="main">

                <header class="major container small">
                    <h3>
                    <?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {

    echo "welcome guest! <br />\n please login ";
    steamlogin(); //login button

}  else {
    include ('steamauth/userInfo.php');
    $url = $steamprofile['profileurl'];
    if ($steamprofile['personastate'] == 0) {
        $state = '<span style="color:#616161";>(Offline)</span>';
        $picture = '<span style="color:#616161";><img src="'.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'" title = "" alt = ""></span>';

    } else if ($steamprofile['personastate'] == 1) {
        $state = '<span style="color:#006EFF";>(Online)</span>';
        $picture = '<span style="border: 10px dotted #006EFF;"><img src="'.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'" title = "" alt = ""></span>';
    } else if ($steamprofile['personastate'] == 2) {
        $state = '<span style="color:#006EFF";>(Busy)</span>';
        $picture = '<span style="border-color:#006EFF border-style: solid";><img src="'.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'" title = "" alt = ""></span>';
    } else if ($steamprofile['personastate'] == 3) {
        $state = '<span style="color:#006EFF";>(Away)</span>';
        $picture = '<span style="border-color:#006EFF border-style: solid";><img src="'.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'" title = "" alt = ""></span>';
    } else if ($steamprofile['personastate'] == 4) {
        $state = '<span style="color:#006EFF";>(Snooze)</span>';
        $picture = '<span style="border-color:#006EFF border-style: solid";><img src="'.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'" title = "" alt = ""></span>';
    } else if ($steamprofile['personastate'] == 5) {
        $state = '<span style="color:#006EFF";>(Looking to Trade)</span>';
        $picture = '<span style="border-color:#006EFF border-style: solid";><img src="'.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'" title = "" alt = ""></span>';
    } else if ($steamprofile['personastate'] == 6) {
        $state = '<span style="color:#006EFF";>(Looking to Play)</span>';
        $picture = '<span style="border-color:#006EFF border-style: solid";><img src="'.$steamprofile['avatarfull'].'" title = "" alt = ""></span>';
    }


    //Protected content
    echo "Welcome back" . "</br> </br>" . $picture ."</br>". $steamprofile['personaname'] . "</br>" .$state .  "</br>".  "Steam ID: ". $steamprofile['steamid'] . "</br>";
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '">Steam Profile</a>'  . "</br> </br>" . "<form action=\"steamauth/logout.php\" method=\"post\"><input value=\"Logout\" type=\"submit\" /></form>"; // Display their avatar!

}    
?>
</h3>
                </header>

                <footer class="major container small">

                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><a href="index.html" class="button">Get Phishers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </footer>

            </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
            <div id="footer">
                <div class="container small">

                    <header class="major last">
                        <h2>Questions or comments?</h2>
                    </header>

                    <p>Program not working? Not detecting the phishers properly? <br \> Send us a message. We'll be sure to back to you as soon as possible.</p>

                    <form method="post" action="#">
                        <div class="row collapse-at-2">
                            <div class="6u">
                                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u">
                                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="6"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <ul class="actions">
                                    <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <ul class="icons">
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-github"><span class="label">Github</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-dribbble"><span class="label">Dribbble</span></a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="copyright">
                        <li>&copy; Steap 2014 All rights reserved.</li><li>Design: <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need something that can process the PHP. What http server are you using?

Comment: I am using Flask and I run the python code above in command prompt. Then I open up http://127.0.0.1:5000/example.php in google chrome, and the output is just a bunch of text.

Comment: @dirn I understand what you are saying. I don't actually have something that can process PHP, cause clearly Flask can't. What software do you suggest I use?

Comment: It depends on which http server you plan on using. I'm not sure what the state of the art is these days but it used to be mod_php with Apache and php-fpm with nginx.

Comment: @Vishwa Iyer, though I think this is a very bad solution to combine python in falsk and php, but it happens when need combine projects. I am now facing the same issue. May I know did you figure it out and dose it works?

Answer (score 1):

`render_template()` isn't support PHP.

You can use `subprocess` to run PHP script:

```py
import subprocess as sp

@app.route('/example.php')
def phpexample():
    out = sp.run(["php", "example.php"], stdout=sp.PIPE)
    return out.stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should run php server (such as Apache or another) on other port (such as 8080) and when you call any php file, make request from your flask server to php server. And result getting from php server show with flask server. I hope, you can find the way how to send request from flask to other server.

Answer (score -2):

Flask is not compatible with php. So it can't read php code.

Answer (score -4):

Have you considered using JQuery Ajax?

Here's an example:

You have a file called get_name.php witch contains:

```
<?php echo "Hello, my name is John"; ?>
```

Using Jquery ajax function I call the get_name.php

```
        $.ajax({
            url : 'get_name.php',
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

The output in the console would be:

> Hello, my name is John

So, with the returned data you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Ok. What exactly would that do? I want to use python and Flask, and   open the php file that I have above. What does PHP and Flask have to do with JQuery. Code you post some kind of code please, because I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: You guys are missing the point.  Whether it's called directly by the browser or by a JS call, the PHP is still renedered at the server.  The OP is trying to figure out how to render PHP (SERVER SIDE) in his python application.